# How to use foundry cast call with a struct that has a uint and string

Tags: foundry

Two uint works, two strings works, but as soon as the struct is a uint and a string I get

"could not decode output. did you specify the wrong function return data type perhaps?"

The command:
cast call 0x5FbDB2315678aeecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 "getTestStruct()(uint,string)"

Answer (score 0):

To get the output decoded properly, you need to wrap the output in another set of parentheses.

`cast call 0x5FbDB2315678aeecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 "getTestStruct()((uint,string))"`

Hope it helps!